# Why can't the three planets(turtles) be drawn at the same time?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I've written a python file to simulate the orbit of the planets, but I can't draw them at the same time.
The turtle document says:"To use multiple turtles on a screen one has to use the object-oriented interface." But how to do that?

```
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-

import math
import turtle

#define a class of planets, which rotate in a oval
class Planet(turtle.Turtle):
    def orbit(self, a, b, t):
        c = math.sqrt(a ** 2 - b ** 2)
        self.goto(a * math.cos(t / 200) + c, b * math.sin(t / 200))

def Sun():
    sun.color('yellow')
    sun.pd()
    sun.showturtle()
    for t in range(1000):
        sun.orbit(0, 0, t)

def Mercury():
    mercury.color('blue')
    mercury.speed(0)
    mercury.pu()
    mercury.goto(50+math.sqrt(50 ** 2 - 49.9 ** 2), 0)
    mercury.pd()
    mercury.showturtle()
    mercury.lt(90)
    for t in range(1000):
        mercury.orbit(50, 49.9, t)

def Earth():
    earth.color('red')
    earth.speed(0)
    earth.pu()
    earth.goto(75+math.sqrt(75 ** 2 - 74.9 ** 2), 0)
    earth.pd()
    earth.showturtle()
    earth.lt(90)
    for t in range(1000):
        earth.orbit(75, 74.9,t)

sun = Planet(shape='circle')
mercury = Planet(shape='circle')
earth = Planet(shape='circle')

turtle.Screen().ontimer(Sun, 100)
turtle.Screen().ontimer(Mercury, 100)
turtle.Screen().ontimer(Earth, 100)

turtle.Screen().mainloop()
```

Comment: How do you know it's not working?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour], and read about [ask], particularly creating a [mcve].

Comment: I just run the program and find that only when the red planet stops orbiting, the blue one would start to orbit.

Comment: You probably need a function which orbits each planet a little, rather than orbiting one, then another. Also the intialisation code for each planet only needs to be called once.

Comment: But how do I switch among different planets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are performing the whole orbit for each planet before moving to the next.

You could create a function to perform the orbits interleaved:

```
def orbit_planets():
    for t in range(1000):
        mercury.orbit(50, 49.9, t)
        earth.orbit(75, 74.9,t)

turtle.Screen().ontimer(orbit_planets, 100)
```

You would also need to remove the orbit code from the planet functions.
Also the planet functions only need calling once to initialise their positions.

However, you can put this code into your `Planet` class:

```
class Planet(turtle.Turtle):
    def __init__(self, colour, a, b):
        turtle.Turtle.__init__(self)
        self.color(colour)
        self.speed(0)
        self.pu()
        self.goto(a + math.sqrt(a ** 2 - b ** 2), 0)
        self.pd()
        self.showturtle()
        self.lt(90)
    ...
```

Then:

```
mercury = Planet('blue', 50, 49.9)
earth = Planet('red', 75, 74.9)
```

Additionally, the planet class could keep track of `a` and `b` (need better names!) and then the `orbit` function wouldn't need the values passing. This means the `Planet` class manages its data and behaviour, the essence of Object Oriented Design:

```
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        ...
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
```

and:

```
    def orbit(self, t):
        c = math.sqrt(self.a ** 2 - self.b ** 2)
        self.goto(self.a * math.cos(t / 200) + c,
                  self.b * math.sin(t / 200))
```

Then the orbit timer function would just be:

```
def orbit_planets():
    for t in range(1000):
        mercury.orbit(t)
        earth.orbit(t)
```

Going further, you could keep the planets in a list:

```
planets = [mercury, earth]

def orbit_planets():
    for t in range(1000):
        for planet in planets:
            planet.orbit(t)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was with @PeterWood up to this point:

> you could keep the planets in a list:
>
> planets = [mercury, earth]

This only makes sense to me if this list is a *class variable* of `Planet` and is automatically updated by the process of creating a new planet.  I.e. not an external entity referred to by an object method!  But even then, does the Sun move the planets (via a list) or do planets move by themselves about the Sun.

Being a fan of timer events, I'd go about this differently.  I'd allow the planets to join without having to register, manually or otherwise, plus add in the ability to simulate the different speeds of planets:

```
from math import sqrt, cos, sin, pi
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

class Star(Turtle):
    def __init__(self, colour):
        super().__init__(shape='circle')

        self.color(colour)

class Planet(Turtle):
    def __init__(self, colour, a, b, period):
        super().__init__(shape='circle')

        self.color(colour)
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.period = period

        self.t = 0
        self.speed('fastest')
        self.shapesize(0.25)

        self.penup()
        self.orbit()
        self.pendown()

    def orbit(self):
        c = sqrt(self.a ** 2 - self.b ** 2)
        angle = self.t / (2 * pi)

        self.goto(self.a * cos(angle) + c, self.b * sin(angle))

        self.t += 1
        screen.ontimer(self.orbit, self.period)

screen = Screen()

sun = Star('yellow')
mercury = Planet('blue', 50, 49.9, 88)
earth = Planet('red', 75, 74.9, 365)

screen.mainloop()
```

This approach has its own issues, both coding-wise and reality-wise, but it keeps things fairly simple and has room to add features:

[image]